# Tcl/tk uploading files

Tags: file-upload, upload, tcl, tk-toolkit, puredata

I'm doing a package manager for Pure Data externals in which the user may have the option to upload the created package in a repository.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a good example from which i can develop a file uploader in tcl.

Can someone help me with an easy to understand code?
Something simple that only needs the file (given by path), url, name and password from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these [Tcl Wiki pages about upload](http://wiki.tcl.tk/upload).